# Exo player DASH Streaming example

Tags: android, video, media-player, exoplayer

I'm trying to play DASH video on android devices with the **ExoPlayer** from Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html). The documentation is very, very poor and I cannot find **some simplest working example with DASH** (if someone did it). In the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VjF638VObA#t=462) it looks simple but in reality there is a lot of unknown objects. I want to use only ExoPlayer library and without using their github demo because it is very complex and I didn't find a way to add my testing URL because all samples are from YouTube.

Thanks

Comment: Ha ha.. Exactly.. Document is poor. Lot of features available but not documented all things

Comment: is the exoplayer  adaptive by itself? or do we need to write extra code?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple dash playing example which will play your stream content into `SimpleExoPlayerView` from `exoplayer-ui`.

Add `SimpleExoPlayerView` to your layout and use the code below

```
    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayer"));
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://your_host/dash/stream.mpd");
    DashMediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
            new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory), null, null);

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));

    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

    exoPlayerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(dashMediaSource);
```

Also add the dependencies to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'
```

Comment: The usage of Dash MediaSource in ExoPlayer is written right, but I think you don't need to add all the dependencies in the gradle as it will include all the sources. These Individual dependencies were released to be used by user by his or her requirement. including  the following will suffice

compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'

Comment: @BawenderYandra I have something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920678/expoplayer-how-to-know-which-url-to-be-played-with-custom-video-view please check. I am new to this

Comment: @alijandro can you send another ocde for 2.9.4 ?

Comment: I tried your solution but am getting the following error ~> Source error.com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ������ ftypisom������...@3:25 in java.io.InputStreamReader@8bd3c66)

Answer (score 1):

You should use new version:

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.0'`

```kotlin
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
val mediaSource = DashMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
exoPlayer?.prepare()
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, it is quite simple to add your testing URL to the ExoPlayer demo application available in Github.

I've tried to explain the exact steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722423/4805417