# Is there a non-youtube example to implement DASH using ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Hi I am looking for an example to configure `ExoPlayer` for `DASH`. But the example I found uses Youtube videos. Is there an example on videos which are not on youtube? Can `DASH` be configured for any video on the internet?

Comment: can you please share the example link that streams videos  from youtube.

Comment: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: This is a simple answer, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386567/exo-player-dash-streaming-example/43678429#43678429)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, ExoPlayer can play any DASH, SmoothStreaming, HLS or MP4 Progressive download over HTTP URLs. 
The demo application provided in ExoPlayer source code can be modified to add any video that will be shown in the startup Activity. To do that, edit https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java file to add a new sample set.
Example:

```
public static final Sample[] CUSTOM_DASH_VIDEOS = new Sample[] {
   new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 1",
    "http://www.somewhere.com/somecontent.mpd?param1=val1&param2=val2", DemoUtil.TYPE_DASH),
   new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 2",
   "http://www.somewhere.com/somecontent.mpd?param1=val1&param2=val2", DemoUtil.TYPE_DASH),
};
```

Now, in https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/SampleChooserActivity.java add a new row in sample adapter.

```
sampleAdapter.add(new Header("Custom DASH Videos"));
sampleAdapter.addAll((Object[]) Samples.CUSTOM_DASH_VIDEOS);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'll try it and let u know

Comment: @SrikanthPeddibhotla If you have worked on `Expoplayer` can you help me.I am having two `url's` one is `dash_url` and second `source_url` how to know which `url` and when to play.I am new to this

Comment: Links provided are resulting in Page not found !

Comment: What is the difference between dash_url and source_url?