# Change the video resolution according to Internet speed

Tags: android

I have a video URL. How can I change The Video pixel quality according to the internet speed like in Facebook?

Comment: The question is too vague. A streaming video hosting could have capabilities to change resolution, an FTP server does not. You should have provided some more details on what kind of hosting is used or give a sample URL at least.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use exoplayer and the dash video format to manage that.

Dash video format is basically a container with different video resolution in it so you'll need all the different quality videos already converted on your hosting server.

Here is a good approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722423/4805417