# Exoplayer how to know which URL to be played with custom video view

Tags: video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am working on an online Video player, I am using `TextureVideoViewMute extends TextureView implements TextureView`. `SurfaceTextureListener` custom class as custom video player.

I am having two `URLs` in my response `source_url`(main URL) and `dash_url`.Now I wanted to use `ExomediaPlayer` for this but I have the following questions.

1. How to categorize which `URL` to be played?
2. Or Whether this will be decided by the player itself while playing?
3. Or we need to use a single `URL` player automatically do his work?

4.Or is it possible combination of `custom video surface view` and `SimpleExoPlayer`?

**How to achieve `adaptive bitrate streaming` like `you-tube 144p 220p 720p... etc` according to network condition?**

I have tried the examples provide on `GIT` but they are either playing `dash_url` or `source_url`

[Exoplayer Sample](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

> Sample code of `Exoplayer`

```
  String videoURL = "http://blueappsoftware.in/layout_design_android_blog.mp4";

    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);
    try {


        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

        Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(videoURL);

        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainAcvtivity", " exoplayer error " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: which URL is supposed to be played by you. DASH or simple HTTP URL?
The player will not decide which URL is to be played. It is up to you to play these media's. It all depends on the end result. So I ask again which URL needs to be played? Why are you using 2 URLs here?

Comment: @BawenderYandra I am using ` HTTP URL` supposed to be play like `YouTube`,  according to network condition `144p 240p 720p ....` How should I achieve this

Comment: What you really need is DASH implementation. DASH stands for Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP. You can check for some implementation online and exoplayer supports DASH mediatype. You find some good examples online too. This is the major feature provided by the exoplayer and youtube uses this feature. Check these links below:
1.[link] (http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html)
2.[link] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386567/exo-player-dash-streaming-example)
The second link provides a detailed implementation also. 
hope this helps you
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current player source (uri) by calling:

`player.currentMediaItem?.playbackProperties?.uri`